# How to save a date in a specific format with timezone in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, spring-data-jpa, timezone

Previously, I used to write to the database.

```
insert into test_table 
    (id, event_date, insert_date) 
values 
    (:id, 
    to_timestamp(:event_date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM"), 
    to_timestamp(:insert_date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM") AT TIME ZONE 'utc')
```

Now I'm trying to rewrite the insertion into the database using hibernate. I wrote Entity, but I don't know how to specify the correct date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM` and `"YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM"` in `UTC`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestTable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //?
    private LocalDateTime eventDate;

    //?
    private LocalDateTime insertDate;
}
```

Also, I'm not sure I've chosen the right type `LocalDateTime`. The date comes to me as a string.

How do I save the date in the correct format? I use Postgresql

Comment: If the data type in PostgreSql is `timestamp with time zone`, it’s probably safest to use `OffsetDateTime` in Java. `Instant` might also work.

Comment: If you receive a string, parse it into a `OffsetDateTime` (or which type you end up needing) in order to put it into your entity. Then Hibernate will take care of the rest. No need to worry about format in the database.

Answer (score 1):

To convert String to LocalDateTime you can follow this steps

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");    
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-01-28T14:29:10.212", formatter);
```

And to convert it into OffsetDateTime you can follow this steps.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC");   // Or another geographic: Europe/Paris
ZoneId defaultZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZoneOffset offset = zoneId.getRules().getOffset(dateTime);
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(dateTime, offset);
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. For your particular format (ISO 8601) you don’t need the formatter since it’s the default format for `LocalDateTime`. For interpreting the date and time in UTC you may simply do `dateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`. To get an `OffsetDateTime` for the default zone I like `dateTime.atZone(defaultZone).toOffsetDateTime()`, but it’s a matter of taste. One may say that your code more directly expresses the intention.